# What elements can I put inside of a form?

Tags: html, forms

and Is something like

```
<form>
   <input ...../>
   <div>
      <input ...../>
   </div>
</form>
```

valid?

**UPDATE**
I've run into trouble because I have been wrapping table rows with forms and as far as I know it's not valid because of the table specification, not the form specification so I'm left wondering if I can wrap a form around other non-table related elements.

I have multiple rows and each row has valid inputs seperated by columns and the inputs from every row will be submitted if I wrap the entire table inside a form. Can I accomplish what I want without javascript? So when I click save I submit the form with hidden inputs that tell me which survey to update in the database.

[image]

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1 so yes it is valid

Comment: Table rows can only have a table as a parent, not a form.

Comment: Excuse the dvorak jibberish :)

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is fairly trivial (“it depends on HTML version, see the specs”). The real problem seems to be something different, but it should be described in its real context, with a descriptive title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

every element has valid child elements that you can use.

you can put almost anything you like inside a form, but not inside a table.
table has a more restricted structure which you must follow.

instead of wrapping table rows with forms, you can wrap the whole table with 1 form and submit all of it and just extract the details you need,

or put 1 cell inside each row with a form in it, and there a new table or list to align your controls.

something of this sort:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: I will accept this as answer because you answered the original question. However; I have added more.

Comment: well basically you you misunderstood html context, you dont wrap elements with a form, you put elements in a form. its different because every element has valid child elements, and not valid parents, so you werent able to wrap table elements with form because it would result in the Form being a direct child of table, which is not allowed. the Form however, accepts all elements therefore you can put anything in it.

Comment: The answer is patently wrong. It is surely incorrect to say that you can put *anything* inside a form, by the specs or in practice. For example, if you try to nest a `form` element in a `form` element, it is a syntax error and may have wild implications.

Comment: you are correct, but i was speaking in general just to answer the question. i have updated my answer according to your suggestion though, thanks.